# Getting directions using routes in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, routing, network, api

I am creating several routes, these routes represent the public transportation network of a city. Now I want to calculate the best combination to go from a point A to a point B using those routes.

Right now I am working with ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.22, but I am open to use there others SDK from Arcgis.

I'm checking the docs, and the [samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/#search/routing), but I have no clue about how to implement this. I am trying to use the [RouteTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/routetask-amd.html), but it looks like I'll need to use another component.

Comment: Do you have a subscription based service available through ArcGIS Online?

Comment: @whyzar I am using the free subscription, I am participating in a contest, so right now I have no money to spend :-)

Comment: I understand, it appears as I provided in the my answer that to use that feature a subscription is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of ArcGIS SDKs, you are working with one that is robust with functionality. However, for your task it requires the following:

[Directions widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_directions.html)

[Class: Directions](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/directions-amd.html)

> The Directions widget uses the World Network Analysis as the default service used to calculate driving directions. This is a subscription based service available through ArcGIS Online. If you have an ArcGIS Server Network Analysis service that you want to use to calculate directions specify the url to the service using the Directions widget routeTaskUrl constructor parameter.

As such, you are tied to the subscription to access this feature. You could look into the World Network Analysis as an option

Comment: I am know the widget, but I don't want to use it. So I gonna try World Network Analysis. Thanks